# Some keys of keyboard not working after pulling water

Tags: keyboard, water-damage

Some keys of my keyboard don't work after pulling water. I unplugged it and then waited the next day to reuse it, but some keys still didn't worked. I disassembled the keyboard and the bottom carpet was still a bit wet, exactly were the keys that were not working are. After draining, some keys re-worked but some keys are still not working.

[image: photo of PCB]

There is brown stains near almost all keys that fault, photo in example (arrows keys down and right fault). I am almost sure this is due to water, like corrosion, or burnt, is it possible ? Some of the 'white dots' are also covered with something. Is it repairable ? If yes, How can I clean this, possibly without products I don't have ? (Like isopropyl alcohol)

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the photo, there is staining (conductive material [water, water soluble]) between traces and this is a main source of difficulty.

You need to replace the keyboard as any further cleaning (alcohol) is most likely to be temporary.

Also, there could have been excessive current or even a short between two of those points.

Replacement parts will be a permanent fix.

Comment: Also, possibly it is still not completely dry.  But the brown stains might be signs of things that got burned.